# Delete specific document from existing envelope in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign.eSign dll in C#. I want to delete document from Docusign

In my case, one envelope consists multiple documents and i want to delete specific document using documentid from an existing envelope

I have used the method exposed by "EnvelopesApi" class like "DeleteDocuments". But it essentially delete a document from draft envelope but I want delete any envelop generated at DocuSign.

Comment: So you want to delete a document after the envelope had been sent? Why? (please say more about your use case, maybe there's a better solution) Did you get an error message when you tried? Please update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

If the envelope is complete, you cannot delete documents from it, or modify it in any way except to void it. 
If the envelope is not complete, but also not in draft, you can use what we call "Correct" to modify it, which enables you to do things like modify the documents that is inside the envelope but only if no recipients have signed them yet. 
In any case, deleting a document is only possible for draft envelopes, as you have already found.